# Is it possible to start expo on a custom domain?

Tags: react-native, expo, ngrok

I am trying to develop React Native app using [Code Server](https://github.com/coder/code-server) hosted in the cloud.

Is it possible to run **expo** with a custom domain, so I can access the link using a mobile device? By default, **expo** is waiting on **exp://10.0.0.186:19000**, and it is not accessible over the Internet.

I can specify a custom port using `expo start --port XXX`, but I don't know if I can specify a custom domain?

I tried using `--tunnel` switch, but it does not work and it outputs:

```
Error starting ngrok: /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/binaries/linux/adb/adb: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--tunnel` option usually just works, assuming you've also installed the `@expo/ngrok` package globally, per the [Expo installation tunneling docs](https://docs.expo.dev/more/expo-cli/#tunneling).

#### Custom domain - Problem

At the time of this writing `@expo/cli` doesn't provide a direct way to use a custom domain, unfortunately. They do provide a way to use sub-domains (see below the solution)

#### Custom domain - Solution

However, if you're like me and aren't satisfied with that answer, you can take matters into your own hands:

1. Get an ngrok account and setup your custom domain (This will require purchasing a personal plan or higher)
2. Patch `@expo/cli` to use your custom domain.

Depending on your package manager, you can use something like [pnpm patch](https://pnpm.io/cli/patch) or [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to create a patch file and ensure it is updated each time you install your node modules.

For `@expo/cli` version 0.7.3, the file you'll want to modify is located in [node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/AsyncNgrok.js](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/packages/%40expo/cli/src/start/server/AsyncNgrok.ts#L162-L163) and will contain the following:

```js
const url = await instance.connect({
    ...urlProps,
    authtoken: NGROK_CONFIG.authToken,
    ...
```

Change it to override the hostname and authToken, and remove the spread of urlProps:

```js
const url = await instance.connect({
    hostname: "<your custom domain>",
    authtoken: process.env.NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN,
    ...
```

I'd suggest using an environment variable rather than directly in the patch file which will be committed to your repository.

Save the file then create and apply your patch file. You should be good to use the `expo start --tunnel` command as normal with your custom ngrok domain configuration.

#### Sub-domains

Not a valid answer to the OP's question, but in case you don't want to purchase a domain and ngrok subscription for the above solution, you can use a **sub-domain** with the `EXPO_TUNNEL_SUBDOMAIN` environment variable, see [Expo environment variables docs](https://docs.expo.dev/more/expo-cli/#environment-variables)

> EXPO_TUNNEL_SUBDOMAIN - Disable using exp.direct as the hostname for --tunnel connections. This enables https:// forwarding which can be used to test universal links on iOS. This may cause unexpected issues with expo-linking and Expo Go. Select the exact subdomain to use by passing a string value that is not one of: true, false, 1, 0.

Which can easily be added to your .env file or package.json start script, for example:

```
"start": "EXPO_TUNNEL_SUBDOMAIN=yoursubdomain expo start --tunnel"
```